# Print a message after Copying folders is done

Tags: process, copy, powershell-5.0

As part of my work I have to copy folders using powershell and display message copy is complete.The file A is of 2.0 GB.A contains some text files and data. Is it possible to display a message after copy is complete. like "Copy of A folder complete".

I have tried using the verbose mode which gives me the files being copied

```
$copychk= Copy-Item -Path "A" -destination "B" -verbose -Recurse
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. `Copy-Item` doesn't return until it's finished. What's stopping you from simply displaying a message afterwards?

Comment: Hi @AnsgarWiechers, thanks for the reply . If we treat Copy as an operation or process, just imagine i don't know how many folders are in A , how would i know whether whole folder  --Recursive copied or not , hence i wanted to display a message after copy is complete . Is there any statement in powershell ?  TIA

Comment: You can check whether the previous operation (in this case `Copy-Item`) was successful or not by evaluating the automatic variable `$?`: `if ($?) { 'success' } else { 'failure' }`.

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers, this is what I was looking for